# Creating Objects in Set or List

Tags: python

Is there a way to create new objects and put them in a set or list in one step? For example:

```
GreatList= [ a = MyObject("a"),
             b = MyObject("b"),
             c = MyObject("c")]
```

Comment: technically:  `great_list = [MyObject('a')]` creates a list and objects in a single step, but it won't bind the object to a local name.  For that you need another step.

Comment: Why do you need the names?

Comment: Maybe I don't... I'm starting from someone else's code, and they've created a bunch of objects, then added them by name to a list.

Comment: `added them by name to a list`? What does that code look like?

Comment: `a = MyObject("a")`
    `b = MyObject("b")`
    `c = MyObject("c")`
`great_list = [a, b, c]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both the `a`, `b`, `c` variables and the list:

```
a, b, c = GreatList = [MyObject("a"), MyObject("b"), MyObject("c")]
```

Consider whether you actually need the individual variables, though. It'd likely be better to just make the list:

```
GreatList = [MyObject("a"), MyObject("b"), MyObject("c")]
```

Note that the `a, b, c = GreatList = ...` thing wouldn't work with a set, since it relies on the list having a fixed iteration order.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've realized that I don't need the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Just eliminate the assignments;

```
 GreatList= [ MyObject("a"), MyObject("b"), MyObject("c")]
```